# Transferring pdfs from computer to android

Tags: samsung-kies, pdf

When trying to transfer pdfs from computer to Galaxy Note II, Samsung Kies reports 'No App to read file'. I have several pdf readers including adobe for android and downloads direct to Note 2 work fine.

Comment: You state a fact, but miss to ask a question. I assume you want to ask "How to transfer PDFs from my computer to my Android device?" -- see my answer below for this. If you rather wanted to ask why Kies acts like that, or how to fix Kies -- maybe you ask again ;)

Comment: If you know to use ADB: simply adb FILE.pdf /sdcard/FOLDER

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to copy files between your computer and your Android device:

- simply connect the two using an USB cable, and mount your Android device's storage to the computer -- then deal with it like with any other drive
- create "shared folders" on your computer, and use an Android app which can deal with them, like e.g. [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)
- Use an app which can share your Android device to your computer, for even more manageability -- like e.g. [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)
- use cloud services like e.g. *Dropbox* or *Google Drive* which are accessible from both, your computer and your Android device, to share documents between the two
- lame, but also listed for completeness: Send the files to your Google Mail account, and then save the attachments from the GMail app

Far from being complete -- but it should give you an idea of what's possible.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply send them by bluetooth

Comment: I think @Izzy left bluetooth out because not all computers are bluetooth-enabled (even though the usb bluetooth caps cost $2). But welcome to Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: That was one of the reasons. Two more are: for bigger files, it's a pain – and OP might even end up with the same issue (BT has issues with file extensions it doesn't "know" sometimes). So if you say "you can simply do this", I assume you've done so successfully? If so, please include that with your answer.